# Couldn't match type `BaseBackend(YesodPersistBackend PersonalPage)' with `SqlBackend'

Tags: haskell, postgresql-9.1, yesod, yesod-forms

I have a problem using persistent and Yesod with postgresql. This is the function that brings problems:

```
postBlogR :: MyHandler Html
postBlogR = do
    ((res, widgetForm), enctype) <- runFormPost blogForm
    case res of
        FormSuccess blog -> do
            blogId <- runDB $ insert blog
            redirect $ HomeR
    _ -> adminLayout [whamlet|<h1>Post Created!|]
```

The trace is:

```
* Couldn't match type `BaseBackend(YesodPersistBackend PersonalPage)'
                 with `SqlBackend'
    arising from a use of `insert'
* In the second argument of `($)', namely `insert blog'
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: blogId <- runDB $ insert blog
  In the expression:
    do { blogId <- runDB $ insert blog;
         redirect $ HomeR }
```

Comment: What exactly is `MyHandler` ?

Comment: It's defined like: type MyHandler = HandlerT PersonalPage IO, PersonalPage is my Foundation type.

Comment: Does the error remain the same if you change the type signature to `Handler Html` ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change.

Comment: Are you using the yesod scaffolding template ?

Comment: No, I'm doing it from scratch. Everything is working except for that runDB. This is the complete code: https://github.com/jmromeroes/personal-webpage/blob/master/app/main.hs

Comment: You are missing `YesodPersist` instances.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. I don't know how I skiped that from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the relevant `YesodPerist` instance. It will be something like this:

```
instance YesodPersist App where
  type YesodPersistBackend App = SqlBackend
  runDB action = do
    master <- getYesod
    runSqlPool action $ appConnPool master
```